# RcppArmadillo::sample function causes RStudio and R to crash

Tags: r, rcpp, armadillo

While using RcppArmadillo::sample function I discovered that using a large input vector causes RStudio to crash. I provide the entire code below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

//[[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector test_func(int N) {
    IntegerVector frame = Range(1, N);
    NumericVector wts = runif(N, 0, 1);
    NumericVector Wts = wts / sum(wts);

    IntegerVector y = RcppArmadillo::sample(frame, N,TRUE, Wts );
    return y;
}
```

Calling `test_func(N=100)` produces the right results. But N greater that 200, for instance `test_func(N=210)`, crashes RStudio as well as RConsole. Is there a mistake I am making?

Answer (score 3):

I cannot replicate this. On either a straight R ression or inside RStudio it just works for me.

I made small corrections to your code:

```
// the following header also include Rcpp and Armadillo headers
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector test_func(int N) {
    Rcpp::IntegerVector frame = Rcpp::Range(1, N);
    Rcpp::NumericVector wts = Rcpp::runif(N, 0.0, 1.0);
    return Rcpp::RcppArmadillo::sample(frame, N, true, wts / Rcpp::sum(wts));
}
```

but none of these should be material.

Note how the code of the `sample()` function throws an excpetion if `N` gets big:

```
if (walker_test < 200) { 
    ProbSampleReplace<IntegerVector>(index, nOrig, size, prob);
} else {
    throw std::range_error("Walker Alias method not implemented. [...]");
}
```

so I think you may be seeing a garden variety error of a mismatch between R, Rcpp, RcppArmadillo.  What platform are you on?  For it is Linux where packages are recompiled.

Comment: I was using R 3.0.3 "Warm Puppy" on Mac OS X version 10.9.2. However, now I updated to R 3.1.0 "Sun Dance" and I get the error message "Walker Alias method not implemented" which I wasn't getting previously on "Warm Puppy". Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I am *very* certain that you simply had mismatched Rcpp and RcppArmadillo before---one locally rebuilt and one not. That does not work, and hence  the exception triggered took your session down.  The `sample()` is by now "old", and gets unit-tested every release.